# Determining a halfspace, from a pair of vectors

Tags: multivariable-calculus

i have an object and a 3d direction vector and position for it . I would like to know how do i determine if a certain point X is in the space below the plan determined by my direction ?

Here is an image that i have drawn to make it more clear . In this image i've made the vector 2d

[image]

Please Help!

Regards, 
Aleandru Badescu

Comment: draw a vector from x to the start of the arrow and ask what the cross product of the two vectors tells you.

Comment: the cross product returns an vector that is perpendicular to both my first vectors. How could i use this information to solve my problem?

Comment: *to both vectors

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding your question: a "direction" (straight line) in the space doesn't determine a plane: you need two straight lines.

Comment: i didn't quite explain right; let me tell you exactly what i want : i have a spaceship A that has a position and a direction, it can be rotated up/down, left/right. If another spaceship B is below Ai would like my spaceship A to rotate down ( so that i may move to it ) . The same think must be done if spaceship B is in A's left or right : if B on my left, rotate left, if B on right, rotate right .

Comment: What do you mean by "below"? In the negative $z$ direction?

Comment: if you imagine a spaceship rotated up/down right/left , 'below' if under the plane determined by the spaceship's deck

Comment: correction : *plain

Comment: "Plane" is the right word here.

Comment: If the spaceship can be rotated arbitrarily in 3d space, a single direction isn't enough to specify its orientation. If, for example, your vector describes which way the nose of the ship is pointing, you still have the freedom to do a "roll". So from just the vector it's impossible to tell what is "below" the ship.

Comment: in my example rolls are not possible. That is why i've specified that it can rotate only up/down left/right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a point $x$, vector $v$, and also some vertical vector, pointing down. Lets call it $g$. If I have understood your problem correctly, your plane contains $(0,0,0)$ (or otherwise you can write $x$ in the coordinate system with origin on the plane), vector $v$, and a vector $w=v\times g$ --- horizontal vector, orthogonal to $v$. I want to interpret $x$ as a vector (from the origin to the point $x$). Then for some $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ vector $x-\alpha g$ is on the plane and $x$ is below the plane if and only if $\alpha>0$. We have
$$(x-\alpha g, v\times w)=0,$$
$$(x-\alpha g, v\times[v\times g])=0,$$
$$(x-\alpha g, v(v,g)-g(v,v))=0,$$
$$(x, v)(v,g)-(x,g)(v,v)=\alpha\bigl((g,v)(g,v)-(g,g)(v,v)\bigr),$$
$$\alpha=\bigl((x, v)(v,g)-(x,g)(v,v)\bigr)/\bigl((g,v)(g,v)-(g,g)(v,v)\bigr).$$

Comment: the vector v is pointing down relative to the objects rotation or parallel to the 0y axis ?

Comment: If Oz is the vertical axis then g=(0,0,-1) and $v$ is the given vector (in the problem you have asked you have a vector and a point). I haven't written anything about rotation.

Comment: ah yes, i got lost in my head. If i would want to find out if an object is in my right, what would i have to change? the g vector ?

Comment: You should find a vector $r$ pointing right and check if $(x,r)>0$. In my notation you can take $r=w=v\times g$.

Comment: Sorry, it should be $r=-w=-v\times g$

Comment: thanks for the edit. i'll try the code and let you know how it went

Comment: the code doesn't quite work. i'm going to insert the code (in more comments because it doesn't all fit in ) and if it's not that much of a bother, maybe you could look at it .

Comment: http://snipt.org/llono/

Comment: I think in your code the pitch axis is not necessarily horizontal. I am not sure I have understood the meaning of your code, but I think you should take $r=ship.orientation.Right$, $\alpha=\pm (x, v\times r)$ in the case of vertical rotation and $\alpha=(x,r)$ in the case of horizontal one.