# point below a plane

Tags: vector-spaces

in R3 (3d) , having a vector perpendicular with a plane ( so we know where is 'up') , how do we determine if a certain point is below our plane ?

Regards,
Alexandru Badescu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't this the same as your question [vector question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7780/vector-question)?  Take the dot product of the perpendicular and the coordinates of the point.  If it is less than zero, the point is below the plane.

Comment: it is the same but the answer didn't quite work .. i guess i might have lost myseft in the details.

Answer (score 10):

If $v$ is the vector that points 'up' and $p_0$ is some point on your plane, and
finally $p$ is the point that might be below the plane, compute the dot product
$v \cdot (p-p_0)$.  This projects the vector to $p$ on the up-direction.
This product is $\lbrace -, 0, + \rbrace$ if $p$ is below, on, above the plane, respectively.